# How to convert blob(image) object into base64 string in titanium/android?

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, base64, appcelerator

I am here to ask a simple question. can you convert the blob type into a base64 string type and then reverse that as well into the blob type? I have seen many and many answers but none is working fine. Please help only if you have tested at you end and that is working fine.

Thanks.

I tried this

```
var imageFile = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile('images8.png');
var oneImage = imageFile.read();
var tempFile = Titanium.Filesystem.createTempFile();
tempFile.write(oneImage);
var contents = tempFile.read();
var x = Ti.Utils.base64encode(contents);
```

Comment: quick answer : yes you can. If you have a more specific question, including what you have, say, actually tried, some code resulting in an error, don't hesitate.

Comment: I have tried but not working, somebody give suggestions but they are not sure about that. TanjaV Please see the about code.

Comment: I found the solution .        
 var str = Ti.Utils.base64encode(imageview1.image);
 Ti.API.info(str);
 var image2=Ti.Utils.base64decode(str);
 imageview2.image=image2;

Comment: add that as an answer and mark it as best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
var str = Ti.Utils.base64encode(imageview1.image);
Ti.API.info(str); 
var image2=Ti.Utils.base64decode(str); 
imageview2.image=image2;
```

Cheers